# How to get hexcode based on the RGB values in iPhone(iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicolor

I have the values of RGBA (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha). I know that we can get the UIColor value based on these things by using

`UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1];`

But is there a way in which i can directly get the Hex code string of a color using the RGBA values in iOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can directly get hex string from a UIColor object. You need to get Red, Green and Blue components from the UIColor object and convert them to hex and append.

You can always create something like this

```
-(NSString *) UIColorToHexString:(UIColor *)uiColor{
    CGColorRef color = [uiColor CGColor];

    int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color);
    int red,green,blue, alpha;
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color);
    if (numComponents == 4){
        red =  (int)(components[0] * 255.0) ;
        green = (int)(components[1] * 255.0);
        blue = (int)(components[2] * 255.0);
        alpha = (int)(components[3] * 255.0);
    }else{
        red  =  (int)(components[0] * 255.0) ;
        green  =  (int)(components[0] * 255.0) ;
        blue  =  (int)(components[0] * 255.0) ;
        alpha = (int)(components[1] * 255.0);
    }

    NSString *hexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02x%02x%02x%02x",
                            alpha,red,green,blue];
    return hexString;
}
```

**EDIT :** in iOS 5.0 you can get red,green,blue components very easly like

```
CGFloat red,green,blue,alpha;
[uicolor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha]
```

so the above function can be changed to

```
-(NSString *) UIColorToHexString:(UIColor *)uiColor{
    CGFloat red,green,blue,alpha;
    [uiColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha]

    NSString *hexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02x%02x%02x%02x",
                            ((int)alpha),((int)red),((int)green),((int)blue)];
    return hexString;
}
```

Comment: This is fine but shades of gray have only 2 components, not 4. Pure black or pure white, for example, won't work with your code. You need to handle cases where `numComponents == 2`; then `R = G = B = components[0]`, and `α = components[1]`.

Comment: @Cyrille Correct.. I just didn't went in to the details of extracting color components since question is more about getting hex value out. Anyway I edited my answer to handle the case of gray.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Your iOS 5 shortcut will fail as you are using the %x format string (which expects an integer) on a CGFloat target (either float or double).  You still need to convert the elements to int.

Comment: @Krishnabhadraish : Hey Krish.. Thanks for the reply. I am getting a string of 9 characters including the # symbol. But a hexcode can contain only 7 characters including the #symbol...Can you just tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I have included alpha of the color in the logic.. If you do not want alpha replace `NSString *hexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02x%02x%02x%02x",
                            alpha,red,green,blue];`  with `NSString *hexString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02x%02x%02x",
                           red,green,blue];`

Comment: I had to multiply red, green and blue with 255 and then the right color code was displayed. If not, it just shows 01000000.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your float values to a `NSString` with this code :

```
float r = 0.5, g = 1.0, b = 1.0, a = 1.0;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
    (int) (r * 255), (int) (g * 255), (int) (b * 255), (int) (a * 255)];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manually convert the color value to hex. It is pretty easy.
if you have color value say

```
float redValue = 0.5;
```

you can compute corresponding hex value as follows.

```
redValue*=255;
    NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",(int)redValue];
```